# laravel codeception run_database_migrations fresh

Tags: laravel, codeception

I want to call `artisan migrate:fresh` before each test.

The docs tell me that I can use `run_database_migrations` to run `artisan migrate`,
but I want get a completely fresh empty database (empty tables).

I know that `cleanup: true` will run all queries in a transaction, but I rather have the option to connect to the DB and see the current state during a test to debug it.

Comment: How about using Db module to reload database from dump before each test?

Comment: @Naktibalda can I use the db module together with the laravel5 module?

Comment: Yes, if Laravel5 module does not use transactions.